# Bomb explosion on Bomberman game

Tags: java

I'm writing a bomberman game in Java and I have already wrote the code for the map of the game (which contains tiles), the players (and their movement in the map) and now I am stuck in the code for the bomb explosion.

I have a `Map` class which contains a 2d array of `Tiles`, which can contain `Player`s, `Block`s and `Bomb`s.
The `Player` object have a method `dropBomb` who calls the method `receiveBomb` from the `Map` object (every `Player` has the reference of the `Map` object) with the position of the bomb and the bomb. When the `Map` method `receiveBomb` is called, the map put the bomb in the correct `Tile`.
My problem is in the explosion of the bomb. Who should care about it? The bomb itself? If it is, should the bomb have the reference for the `Tile` that contains it? Until now my tile haven't need the `Map` reference.

One possibility that I thought is to have the `Tile` reference inside the `Bomb` object, so, when the bomb explodes (and the bomb knows when it should explode) it calls a method in the tile object for the explosion and the tile calls a method in the map. By the way, I don't know this is a good idea. What should I do?

```
public class Tile {

private boolean available; //if the tile is not occupied by a indestructible block or bomb
private List<Entity> entities; //you can have more than one player at a tile
public boolean receiveEntity(Entity entity) {
    boolean received = false;
    if (available) {
        this.entities.add(entity);
        received = true;
        if (entity instanceof Block || entity instanceof Bomb) {
            available = false;
        }
    }
    return received;        
}

public boolean removePlayer(Player player) {
    return entities.remove(player);
}
}
```

Player class:

```
public class Player implements Entity {

private Map gameMap;
private int posX;
private int posY;
private int explosionRange; //the explosion range for bombs
public Player(int posX, int posY, Map gameMap) {
    this.gameMap = gameMap;
    this.posX = posX;
    this.posY = posY;
    this.explosionRange = 1;
}

public void dropBomb() {
    gameMap.receiveBomb(new Bomb(explosionRange), posX, posY);
}
}
```

Map class:

```
public class Map {

private Grid<Tile> tileGrid;
private int width;
private int height;

public Map(int width, int height, BuildingStrategy buildingStrategy) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.tileGrid = new Grid<Tile>(width, height);  
    buildingStrategy.buildMap(this);
}   
public void receiveBomb(Bomb bomb, int posX, int posY) {
    tileGrid.get(posX, posY).receiveEntity(bomb);
}
}
```

I have omitted the movement methods, because the movement is already fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I have always learned, and live by the rule "the table paints itself". The painter might choose the color and call the method, the floor might decide how the leaks and splatter is shown, but the table paints itself.*

Back to your issue: **the bomb explodes itself**. This way you can have different effects of different bombs. The bomb has an effect on the tile, and the tile reacts to that.

Example: A bomb has a force and a type of explosion. The bomb, (occupying one and one tile only I think?) will 'give' it's effect to a tile.

Now it's the tile that deals with distributing this force. Lets say you have several kinds of bombs, one power (lets say a number between 1 and 10), and two type (lets say normal, incendiary, freeze).

Now your bomb explodes, and because your avatar is a level 5 fire-mage, your bombs are of power 4 and type incendiary. So you say to your tile: I explode with power 4 and I am setting you on fire!

Now the tile comes in to play. Any tile that gets 'touched' by the force of an explosion needs to call it's "Exploded" function to do stuff. If it is also on fire, there is more to do in the "onFire" function

What tiles are 'exploded' comes from force. Normal tiles with force 4 will give the expotion off to all squares within a range of 4, but if it is a special tile (it knows that from itself), like a mountain tile, it might not be able to advance with that force.

Tile 1 explodes with 4 and gives it to adjacent tiles with force 3. One of those tiles might be a wall, so doens't do anything further. Another is a normal tile, and explodes, and continues giving it forward with force 2, etc. If it is a 'water' tile, the explosion is pushed ofrward, but the fire isn't, etc

so:

- bomb explodes itself and gives calls the tiles explosion function
- tile is exploded and pushes explosion forward according to tile-type.
- subsequent tiles explode because of this.

In the end it might look like most of the work is done by the tiles, and this is probably even the case. but the first steps: the calculation of the force, type, and the first calls are from the bomb. The bomb explodes. And then the explosion has an effect on the tile. The tile handles that, and if needed propagates it.

Comment: Should the bomb have the reference for the tile? Also, should i consider to use the reference of adjacent tiles for each tile instead of a 2d array?

Comment: A bomb is placed on a tile and should know it is on the tile, so yes, it has a tile-reference. A tile should known either by linking (not sure you need it) or by 'calculation' what tiles are adjacent

Answer (score 0):

Your Map should be responsible for the explosion, as it is for every other tile on the map. After all, what is an explosion if not for another tile-type that disappears after a few seconds?

When your game loop calls the update method on the Map object your map should figure out:

- What tile is the bomb on
- Ask the bomb how far the reach is
- Figure out what's in the adjacent tiles that the bomb can reach

Think of your design as a series of events, taken care of one by one in the game loop before eventually being drawn. When your bomb is dropped, it raises an event to the Map in the form of `recieveBomb()` with the Map being the event controller.

I believe this question fits better in a discussion format and not a Q&A format. It's hard to tell you what is the "correct design" without understanding the overall architecture.

Comment: I disagree with your second step `ask the bomb how far the reach is`. The bomb should decide to explode (mabye it's a timed bomb? only the bomb should 'know' that. When the bomb decides to explode, it gives some effect to the tile, and then the tile can decide if it continues that force somewhere.

Comment: True, but in bomberman each player has powerups that define how far their bombs reach, so that absolutely must be defined by the bomb as created by the player. The Map needs to be aware of the reach in order to figure out how many adjacent tiles on the X,Y lines to mark as exploding.

Comment: you could pass the reach to the tile, instead of requesting it. a minor difference maybe, but it is the type of thingy this questoin asked for i think.

Answer (score 0):

The Map should be the responsible one for handling a bomb explosion.

I would suggest having a queue in the Map, that contains all the bombs present. Also, your bombs should have a timer (i.e., CreationTime) so that as bombs get pushed into the queue, you check each bomb in the queue for how long they have been in there and if applicable "explode" them.

Add a `ExplodeBomb` function in the Map that checks all 4 directions and handle the tiles accordingly.